# why isn't tkinter displaying my image (.gif)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so I'm making a contacts list following a tutorial & I was trying to display a picture of the logo in column 0 & row 0, but it did not display but I have the correct format (.gif). still did not work, the size of the image is `98x98` is there a specific size?
the code:

```
class Contacts:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def create_left_icon(self):
        photo = PhotoImage(file='icons/logo.gif')
        label = Label(image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I Used Tkinter's `PhotoImage` module.

Comment: Your never calling your method, somewhere inside `__init__` say `self.create_left_icon()` or find other ways to call it.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. In the code you posted, `create_left_icon` is never called. We need to see how and when you're calling it.